# How create a single dropdrown and place it on every page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'mworking on a website and requirement is that to "create a single dropdown that contains the time zone info . and place it on everypage? 
How could i do it?

This is for the development of a dropdown list in asp.net c# language.

I dont want to repeat code on everypage of dropdown list i just want to use my previous code of dropdown list like "include" in php .

Comment: If you are using master page, then you can put your the dropdown in the master page. So every child page of master page will have the dropdown list displayed. You also can create a user control (.ascx) which has dropdown in it and use that control in all the aspx pages.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-master-page-in-asp-net/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/interacting-with-the-master-page-from-the-content-page-cs

Answer (score 0):

Use a Layout when creating another view or you can add & edit the _Layout.cshtml in the Shared Folder under Views and inherit it to every views that you create by ticking the "Use a Layout Page" upon adding the views.

See this link for reference:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-view-in-mvc-5/